# Running multiple VBA with python

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I have to perform 200 calculations with an excel spreadsheet, I'm trying to do it through python.
The excel file has 3 macros, and I need to execute each of them every time in order to get all the results.
I manage to run the first macro and get the results, but when I run the second macro, python stops working (like it is in an infinite loop).
I checked the excel file for the same values in my python routine and it works.
This is the code I'm using:

```
for i in range(0,2):
    app = xw.App(visible=False)
    # open excel file
    wb = app.books.open("original.xlsm")
    sheet= wb.sheets['Input-Output']
    # get values for case i
    soil_type = inputs.soil_type.iloc[i] 
    cable_diam = round(inputs.diameter.iloc[i],3)
    d50 = round(inputs.d50.iloc[i],3)
    lin_weight = round(inputs.linear_weight.iloc[i],2)
    mu = round(inputs.mu.iloc[i],2)
    wd =  round(inputs.wd.iloc[i],2)
    hs = round(inputs.hs.iloc[i],2)
    tp = round(inputs.tp.iloc[i],1)
    vs = round(inputs.vs.iloc[i],2)
    embed = round(inputs['cable embedment'].iloc[i],3)
    # change values
    sheet.range('C8').value = C8
    sheet.range('C11').value = C11
    sheet.range('C15').value = C15
    sheet.range('C17').value = C17
    sheet.range('C19').value = C19

    sheet.range('C20').value = C20
    sheet.range('C21').value = C21
    sheet.range('C23').value = C23
    sheet.range('C29').value = C29
  

    run_macro_1 = wb.app.macro('m1')
    run_macro_2 = wb.app.macro('emb.m2')
    run_macro_3 = wb.app.macro('m3')
    run_macro_1()
    run_macro_2()
    run_macro_3()
    
    # file name
    name = 'omni_'+'case_' + str(i+1) + '.xlsm'
    # getting_results
    uplift_cond.append(sheet.range('H13').value)
    uplift_cond2.append(sheet.range('H15').value)
    lat_cond.append(sheet.range('G35').value)
    lat_cond2.append(sheet.range('G36').value)
    print(i)
    # save 
    wb.save(name)
    wb.close()

    # close excel and quit

    app.quit()
```

Many thanks for your help

Comment: Not sure how you expect anyone to answer this when they have no knowledge of what the 3 macros are doing.  Why wouldn't you do the analysis in python?  That would seem a better way then running the 3 macros...

Comment: I have to use an existant tool that was done in Excel. I already solve the problem. Thanks for your very constructive response